# Swift control flow:

Tags: facebook, swift, control-flow

Below in my code I am trying to use the Facebook SDK to get a list of my friends and show them on another view controller. I call the function `createFriendsInfo(data : NSArray)` in the function `loginViewShowingLoggedInUser`. The function is being called and the data is being populated in arrays.

The problem is that after the loop in `createFriendsInfo` is finished populating the data in the arrays, the control directly goes to the view controller. Instead, it should first finish executing the statement after the loop in the function and then the control should go back to `loginViewShowingLoggedInUser` where `performSegueWithIdentifier:` should be executed.

I am new to Swift, and I need some help understanding the control flow in my code.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class FBViewController : UIViewController, FBLoginViewDelegate {


    @IBOutlet var fbLogin: FBLoginView!
    var friendNames : [String] = []
    var friendPics : [UIImage] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //var fbl: FBLoginView = FBLoginView() //create login button on UIController
        //self.view.addSubview(fbl)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        self.fbLogin.delegate = self
        self.fbLogin.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]


    }

    func createFriendsInfo(data : NSArray)
    {
        println("Start Create")
        for i in 0...data.count {
            let valueDict : NSDictionary = data[i] as NSDictionary
            let userID = valueDict.objectForKey("id") as String
            self.friendNames.append(valueDict.objectForKey("name") as String)
            let id = valueDict.objectForKey("name") as String
            var url = NSURL (string : "http://graph.facebook.com/\(userID)/picture?type=large")
            let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
            let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

            var response: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSURLResponse?>=nil
            var error: NSErrorPointer = nil
            if let ImageData : NSData = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(urlRequest, returningResponse: response, error:nil)?
            {
                var image = UIImage( data : ImageData)
                self.friendPics.append(image!)
                println("Image Appended")
            }
        }

        println("Create Friends Info \(self.friendNames.count) \(self.friendPics.count) ")
    }


    // Facebook Delegate Methods

    func loginViewShowingLoggedInUser(loginView : FBLoginView!) {

                println("Start Fetched")
                var friendsRequest : FBRequest = FBRequest.requestForMyFriends()
                friendsRequest.startWithCompletionHandler{(connection:FBRequestConnection!, result:AnyObject!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
                    var resultdict = result as NSDictionary
                    println("Result Dict: \(resultdict)")
                    var Data : NSArray = resultdict.objectForKey("data") as NSArray
                    self.createFriendsInfo(Data)
                    println("Perform \(self.friendNames.count) \(self.friendPics.count) ")
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toFriendList", sender: self)
                    println("Perform \(self.friendNames.count) \(self.friendPics.count) ")
        //
                }

        //self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toFriendList", sender: self)

    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func loginViewFetchedUserInfo(loginView : FBLoginView!, user: FBGraphUser) {
    }

    func loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser(loginView : FBLoginView!) {
        println("User Logged Out")
        self.friendNames = []
        self.friendPics = []
        println("Logout \(self.friendNames.count) \(self.friendPics.count) ")
    }

    func loginView(loginView : FBLoginView!, handleError:NSError) {
        println("Error: \(handleError.localizedDescription)")
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if((segue.identifier == "toFriendList" ) && (self.friendNames.count > 0))
        {
            var fl : friendList = segue.destinationViewController as friendList
            println("Prepare \(self.friendNames.count) \(self.friendPics.count) ")
            fl.name1 = self.friendNames
            fl.profilepics1 = self.friendPics
        }

    }






}
```

Comment: Does `FBRequest.friendsRequest.startWithCompletionHandler` return asynchronously?

Comment: Yes it does asynchronusly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop in `createFriendsInfo` has the wrong upper bound; typically would be `0..<data.count`.  As it is,

```
for i in 0...data.count {
  let valueDict : NSDictionary = data[i] as NSDictionary
  // ...
```

will 'fail' when `i == data.count`.

But, as for the control flow, the `friendsRequest` completion handler most definately does not run on the main queue.  That means that the `performSegueWithIdentifier` will 'get lost'.  Change your code to:

```
func loginViewShowingLoggedInUser(loginView : FBLoginView!) {
  println("Start Fetched")
  var friendsRequest : FBRequest = FBRequest.requestForMyFriends()

  friendsRequest.startWithCompletionHandler{
      (connection:FBRequestConnection!, result:AnyObject!, error:NSError!) -> Void in
    var resultdict = result as NSDictionary
    println("Result Dict: \(resultdict)")
    var Data : NSArray = resultdict.objectForKey("data") as NSArray
    self.createFriendsInfo(Data)
    println("Perform \(self.friendNames.count) \(self.friendPics.count) ")
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
      self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toFriendList", sender: self)
      println("Perform \(self.friendNames.count) \(self.friendPics.count) ")
      //
    }
  }
}
```

All UI actions MUST be performed on the main queue.

Note that you may need to declare `self` as `unowned` in the closure for `dispatch_async` (I forget the current Swift status on this)